# Mysql Table Indexing in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, indexing

I have a MYsql database containing names of books, authors and other details.

Which indexing engine can search them?

I wanted to use [Sphider](http://www.sphider.eu/).

Will it work for `MySQL` databases?

Comment: What kind of search are you trying to do? What does the searched data look like?

Comment: Sphider is for spidering/indexing a website, rather than a database.  If you have your data exposed via a set of structured webpages, then perhaps. [Read the docs](http://www.sphider.eu/docs.php).

Comment: `Sphider` is good for  setting up an search engine for your own website, but it isn't made as a general database search engine.  You'd need another tool for that.

Comment: Why can you not just use MySQL search functionality? Is there a good reason to not just use Full Text Searches or `LIKE`? Do you have huge amounts of data?

Comment: You may want to have a look at [apache solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)

Comment: Why dont you go for lucene or solr. Those are premium....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution 1: 
Use MyISAM table engine for your tables that contain the records you want to search. Then you can create indexes on columns you want to search and then apply full text search functions.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html

Note: When using MyISAM you will not have transactional capabilities, and tables might get corrupted (recovery is difficult). Also, as of MySQL 5.6.4 InnoDB has full text support (though it's a new feature so it might be buggy and benchmarks are still not ample).

Solution 2:
Use Sphinx search server. It is super fast and distributed search system. Sphinx will pull fields you want to index from your MySQL database and index them. Then you can either use Sphinx SQL to fetch the document IDs matching your query or use Sphinx API (provided for well known languages) to get document IDs matching.
http://sphinxsearch.com/

Sphinx is super fast when it comes to indexing and query serving. It's worth taking a look at. I would recommend it.

Comment: Solution 1 means no transactions, period, and brittle tables that might get corrupted and prove difficult to recover. It is far from ideal. Solution 2 is much more robust.

Comment: Yup that's why I recommended Sphinx at the end. BTW Innodb now has Full text searching capability. If you are using MySQL 5.6.4 (or latest InnoDB) then you will get transactions, robust tables and great recovery.

Comment: You should amend your answer to include the InnoDB index feature. Using MyISAM is super hack compared to that.

Comment: Done. 

As I cannot post more hyperlinks in my posts here is a very nice webminar on full text search (with some nice benchmarks)

http://www.percona.com/webinars/2012-08-22-full-text-search-throwdown

Answer (score 2):

If all your data is already in a mysql database, then you don't need any search/indexing engine.
Use one of the extensions available in PHP to query mysql databases: [MySQLi or PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).
Read the documentation for the extension, learn how to use the functions.

Then you will be able to write PHP/MySQL code to manipulate the data in your database.

Comment: A search engine can provide a significant boost to both performance and intelligence when searching.